# AndroidでのNotificationをユーザーに取り消し可能にする方法

Tags: android, notification

アプリの状態によって、Notificationをユーザーに取り消し可能状態と取り消し禁止状態とで偏移させたいのですが、取り消すことの出来ない状態になってしまいます。

```
    PlayItem playingItem = state.getCurrentPlayItem();
    // Notification
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setContentIntent(pi);
    builder.setDefaults(0);
    builder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    builder.setContentTitle(playingItem.getTitle());
    builder.setContentText(playingItem.getAuthor());
    builder.setWhen(0);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifiy_small);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_notifiy_large));


    if (state.isPreparing() || state.isPlaying()) {
        builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_av_pause, getString(R.string.player_pause),
                PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(ACTION_PAUSE), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    } else {
        builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_av_play_arrow, getString(R.string.player_pause),
                PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(ACTION_PLAY), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    }
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_av_skip_next, getString(R.string.player_next),
            PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(ACTION_SKIP), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_player_stiop, getString(R.string.player_stop),
            PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(ACTION_STOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    if (state.isPreparing() || state.isPlaying()) {
        // Notificationを作成して通知
        Notification notify = builder.build();
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(NOTIFICATION_PLAYER_ID, notify);
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_PLAYER_ID, notify);
    } else {
        //ここで通知をユーザーに削除可能な状態としたい
        stopForeground(false);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        Notification notify = builder.build();
        notify.flags |= NotificationCompat.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(NOTIFICATION_PLAYER_ID, notify);
    }
```

Comment: 適当な回答なのでコメントで。

Notification本体(例えばアイコン)をタップした場合、おそらく取り消しができるのではありませんか。質問者様がお聞きしたいのは`builder.addAction`で登録した内容をタップしたときかなぁと思いました。
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883534/how-to-dismiss-android-notification-after-action-has-been-clicked　 などの回答を見るに、actionのとき自動的にdismissできるAPIはないので`Intent`の受付先で` NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(getIntent().getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, -1));`みたいなことをしないといけないらしいです...

Comment: コメント有難うございます。消したいのはNotification本体をタップした場合、Notificationを横スライドまたはOS側の取り消しボタンをタップした場合です。
通常はsetAutoCancelを設定すれば、タップした時に通知は消えるとおもうのですが、そうはなりません。横スライド削除も動作せず、取り消しボタンも出てきません。